# How to use $lt and $gte without a common range?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

If I want to get response_due of customer above 7 (`$gte: 7`) or less than 3 (`$lt: 3`), what my query should look like with `$match` aggregation?

I tried to do something like this:

```
db.customers.aggregation({$match: {response_due : {$gte: 7, $lt: 3}}})
```

But of course it did not work.
Also, I tried to do something like this:

```
db.customers.aggregation({$match: {$or: [ { $gt: [ "$response_due", 7 ] }, { $lt: [ "$response_due", 3 ] } ] }})
```

But it also did not work.

What is the solution and the best approach?

P.S: I use native MongoDB driver for NodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> db.customers.aggregation({$match: {$or: [ { $gt: [ "$response_due", 7 ] }, { $lt: [ "$response_due", 3 ] } ] }})

You have used expression syntax of [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) and [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) it will support when you add [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator before `$or` operator,

```
db.customers.aggregation([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          { $gt: [ "$response_due", 7 ] }, 
          { $lt: [ "$response_due", 3 ] } 
        ] 
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But originally you have to go without expression match condition of [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) and [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt) operators, specifying field name and separate condition operator,

```
db.customers.aggregation([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { response_due: { $gte: 7 } },
        { response_due: { $lt: 3 } }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```